# Как парсить данные из logcat?

Tags: java, android

Допустим есть недокументированные методы в андроид.
Но нужный результат можно спарсить в logcat, как правильно это сделать в приложении для Android.

Смотрел пример https://github.com/djkevincr/sep_project/tree/master/ussd, но он увы не рабочий.

Comment: Парсить результат выполнения метода из логката - это просто умопомрачительный костыль, который будет работать только на 1 телефоне. На других вывод результата в лог будет просто отключен.  Приведите метод, который вы хотите использовать

Comment: @metalurgus Вот здесь я задал вопрос https://toster.ru/q/222061 на который хотелось бы знать ответ, как раз то что мне и нужно (logcat)

Answer (score 3):

Сразу предупреждлаю, что с android 4.1 доступ приложениям к системным логам закрыт, даже если вы добавите разрешение `android.permission.READ_LOGS` в манифест. Вы можете читать только логи своего приложения.

В целом, процесс достаточно простой. Создаете отдельный поток, из которого запускаете новый дочерний процесс `adb logcat` с нужнфми вам ключами, читаете его вывод построчно и парсите строки.

Пример такого потока. Запускается сначала `adb logcat -b radio -c`, затем `adb logcat -b radio`. (Из рабочего приложения).

```
public class LogReader extends Thread {
    public final String CLEAR_LOG_CMD = "logcat -b radio -c";
    public final String LOGCAT_CMD = "logcat -b radio";
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

    protected Process mLogcatProc = null;

    public void run() {
        try {
            try {
                // Очищаем журнал
                final Process clearLogProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CLEAR_LOG_CMD);
                clearLogProc.waitFor();
                clearLogProc.destroy();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Запускаем процесс, вывод которого будем читать построчно
            mLogcatProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(LOGCAT_CMD);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            onError("Can't start " + LOGCAT_CMD, e);
            return;
        }

        // Читаем вывод
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            reader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mLogcatProc.getInputStream()),
                            BUFFER_SIZE);

            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                onNewline(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            onError("Error reading from process " + LOGCAT_CMD, e);
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }

            stopCatter();
        }
    }

    public void stopCatter() {
        if (mLogcatProc == null)
            return;

        mLogcatProc.destroy();
        mLogcatProc = null;
    }

    private void onError(String msg, Throwable e) {
        Log.e("LogReader", msg, e);
    }

    private void onNewline(String line) {
        // Парсим строку
    }
}
```

Как дать своему приложению доступ на чтение системных логов, имея права root, можно подсмотреть в ответе [11461650 READ_LOGS permission on Jelly Bean (api 16)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461650/read-logs-permission-on-jelly-bean-api-16)

Стоит учитывать, что в логах на разных телефонах нужных вам строк может и не быть, либо они будут в другом формате. Недокументированные методы - это всегда методы, работу и наличие которых никто не гарантирует. Разработчики прошивок меняют внутренности системы, адаптируя работу по свои платформы. Да и сами разработчики android переписывают некоторые подсистемы очень часто. То есть с таким подходом, будьте готовы, что вам придется постоянно адаптироваться под новые телефоны и прошивки.

По вашей ссылке пример очень похож. Скорее всего, он у вас не работает, потому что вы запускаете его на android >= 4.1, либо вывод logcat на вашем телефоне не совпадает с тем форматом, который парсит автор.

Comment: Походу из за Android 4.2.1 )